# KMSAccessDeniedException when reading messages from Amazon Kinesis

Tags: encryption, java, streaming, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to consume messages in a Java Application from a Kinesis Stream, the stream is owned by another AWS account.

When I read the message the following error is then thrown:

```
com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.AmazonKinesisException: User ARTRIOONHGFA4UYTVBSF3:crossAccountTest is not authorized to decrypt records in stream 123456123456:stream-name:1234567890 (Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 400; Error Code: KMSAccessDeniedException; Request ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1579)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1249)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
 at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1831)
 at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1807)
 at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.getRecords(AmazonKinesisClient.java:912)
 at com.kafka.connect.KinesisSourceTask.poll(KinesisSourceTask.java:89)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:244)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:220)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The IAM roles allow access to the stream and the KMS key used to encrypt the stream. I have tried assuming the role on the CLI and consuming messages from there, but have the same error message. 
`An error occurred (KMSAccessDeniedException) when calling the GetRecords operation: User ARTRIOONHGFA4UYTVBSF3:crossAccountTest is not authorized to decrypt records in stream 123456123456:stream-name:1234567890`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the KMS key used to encrypt the stream did not have an explicit `Allow` permission that would let the assumed role access the key.

The key policies were updated to include

```
{
            "Sid": "Allow use of the NDH Role Assuming Accessing the Kinesis Data Stream",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam:: 123456123456:role/assumed-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kinesis:ap-southeast-2: 123456123456:stream/stream-name"
            ]
}
```